# Adding values if record is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with the following data:

```
CUSIP   SEDOL   DESC
1111    NULL    ABC Corp
1234    NULL    ABCD Corp
NULL    12      ABCDE Corp
```

Now I have another table on a different databse server:

```
CUSIP   SEDOL   DESC
1111    18      ABC Corp
1234    19      ABCD Corp
1246    12      ABCDE Corp
```

How do i go about in populating the NULL values in the first table based on the values provided in table in a different database server? (I'm using SQL Server 2005)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

Comment: With three values you'd be as well to just type them in. Or explain a bit more how we can match one to the other. Is SEDOL unique? CUSIP? SEDOL + DESC? Any two parts matching constitutes a match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update table1 set
sedol = (select sedol from database2.table2 where desc = table1.desc)
where sedol is null;
```

It is not clear from your question if `cusip` is what's important, so you might need instead:

```
update table1 set
sedol = (select sedol from database2.table2 where cusip = table1.cusip)
where sedol is null;
```

To update cusip, use this:

```
update table1 set
cusip = (select cusip from database2.table2
         where desc = table1.desc
         and sedol = table2.sedol)
where cusip is null;
```

Comment: I think "table in a different database server" is his main problem

Comment: @Bohemian can you please tell me what you think of my solution? will it work? thank you so much for your feedback.

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов Firtly, just because something "Works", doesn't make it "good". Your query would work, but it would update every row and (depending on internal optimizations) would run the subquery for every row. Removing the `coalesce()` and adding `where sedol is null` is semantically equivalent, but more efficient, as only those rows *needing* update are locked for update, and potentially *much* more efficient due to avoiding locks *and* avoiding many pointless subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update BadTable set BadTable.SEDOL=Coalesce(BadTable.SEDOL,GoodTable.SEDOL) from GoodTable where GoodTable.[DESC]=BadTable.[DESC]
```

maybe

```
where GoodTable.[CUSID]=BadTable.[CUSID]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1 t1
set t1.sedol 
   = coalesce (t1.sedol,(select top 1 sedol 
                     from table2 
                     where t1.cusip = cusip
                     and t1.desc = desc))
```

Answer (score 0):

First add a linked server as per Tim's comment.

Then a number of queries like this depdning on matching rules.

```
Update
  table1
Set
  Sedol = t2.Sedol
From
  table1 t1
    Inner Join
  server2.db2.schema2.table2 t2
    On t1.CusIP = t2.CusIP and t1.[Desc] = t2.[Desc] And t1.Sedol Is Null
```

Answer (score 0):

After add linked server you script will be look

```
MERGE dbo.your_table AS target
USING [AnotherServer].dbo.your_table AS source
ON (target.[DESC] = source.[DESC])
WHEN MATCHED AND (target.CUSIP IS NULL OR target.SEDOL IS NULL)
  THEN UPDATE SET target.CUSIP = source.CUSIP,
                  target.SEDOL = source.SEDOL;
```